# How to restore Multibit HD keys using cloud .zip.aes files

Tags: multibit

weird thing happened to me. I kept backup in cloud under Dropbox/bitcoinz. I can see many mbhd-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.zip.aes files, I also have wallet words but when I try to restore old wallet after fresh install on new pc, I enter the words and select coud backup filder, it says that no backup files were found.

But they are there, present.

So I clicked on ok, window disappeared and new wallet opened. I entered my password (the one I used with old backuped wallet), it got accepted and bitcoin started to sync.

But when it finished, it showed 0 BTC. And moreover, I found nowhere again the option, to restore from cloud backup .zip.aes files.

What happened here? How to restore bitcoins using wallet words and online backup?

Thanks

Comment: Does restoring with just your datestamp, wallet words, and password work?

Comment: there is no such option where I could enter datestamp. It always asks only for wallet words, then starts synchronising

Answer (score 0):

If you have your seed words, I would suggest giving up on Multibit and either using "Simple Bitcoin Wallet" or "Breadwallet", apps for Android/iOS - other users are saying they are able to retrieve their Bitcoin using their previously MultiBit-managed Bitcoin holdings by simply importing their seed words. If you get this to work, please let me know.

MultiBit has been discontinued as a supported product and hundreds of users are having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the wallet words you don't need any backup. Try [restoring in Electrum](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/) since multibit is end of life now.